# How to make linux sed command find match ip address

Tags: linux, sed, grep, scripting, ip-address

In my Linux system, executing `listdata.sh` outputs:

```
{
  "111.111.111.111:11957": 1,
  "222.222.222.222:9999": 1,
  "333.333.333.333:9999": 1,
  "[::]:0": 1,
  "444.444.444.444:9999": 1,
  "d6iiugkkjfgt3kt2z.onion:47500": 1,
  "555.555.555.555:11957": 1,
  "666.666.666.666:9999": 1,
  "nv52misrzsuyre6.onion:47509": 1,
  "777.777.777.777:9999": 1,
  ":9999": 1,
  "[::]:0": 1
}
```

If my ip is `222.222.222.222`
I need to check when run linux command.

"some command" "222.222.222.222" "if found my ip" do nothing "if not found" "do something"

Data list sometime go tor address too sometime show IPv6

Comment: Pay attention you also have got there Tor addresses. Do you want to process them?

Comment: Yes tor address in data list too sometime.

Comment: You might be compromising the identity of your Tor server posting logs from it. But they were changed, right?

Comment: data query from public my server ipv4 I want to check my server still on list or not. If not do something for let me to know only that.

Comment: I know that command it will show
"222.222.222.222:9999": 1,
I want to do more than this ex.

grep "222.222.222.222" !== listdata.sh mail to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For doing actions if your IP address 222.222.222.222 is not found, you can write a `bash` script as it as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
listdata.sh | grep "\"222\.222\.222\.222:"  > /dev/null
if [ $? -ne 0 ]   # if grep not successful 
then
    ... do some actions
fi
```

Comment: maybe 
listdata.sh | grep  "\"222.222.222.222:" > /dev/null 
Right?
listdata.sh that command for query IP list.

Comment: @ChonlathitWanpean Correct.

Comment: (there are other ways with bash string operators, this solution is easier to understand)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Rui F Ribeiro
This my final scripts

```
#!/bin/bash
listdata.sh | grep "\"222.222.222.222:"  > /dev/null
if [ $? -ne 0 ]   # if grep not successful 
then
        addIPtolist.sh > /dev/null
        echo "`date -u` Not in list"  >> /var/log/listdata.log
        exit
fi
        echo "`date -u` OK Still in list"   >> /var/log/listdata.log
```

And this my loop bash

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
        listdata.sh
        sleep  60
done
```

Comment: Note that (unless you add a fixed strings switch, or escape it) `.` will match *any* single character - not just a literal period