# Use curl command output to send email

Tags: shell-script, curl, ssmtp

My goal is to monitor a web page for text and trigger an email to myself either if the text is found, or if it is not, whichever is easier. I know there are some packages out there already to do this, but I'm trying to learn a bit more command line in the process of figuring this out.

The use case is to search for text like "sale starting in" or something like that, so I get an alert when that text is no longer there.

I've done some digging and have the two commands I need, but want to be able to tie them together into a job that I can schedule in cron. A single shell command line would be preferred. I do have perl installed if a script is needed.

An example of a successful search is

```
curl -s -k http://www.scifi-review.net | grep stettin
```

result: the source code line with the pattern mach

An example of no result is

```
curl -s -k http://www.scifi-review.net | grep xxxxxxx
```

result: just goes back to command line

My email command (I installed an configured ssmtp)

```
echo "Subject: Test"| ssmtp myemail@domain.com
```

I'm looking at doing something like this:

If Curl command has NO output, run the email command. (preferred)

or

If Curl command HAS output, run the email command.

Comment: see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/428917/how-to-make-linux-sed-command-find-match-ip-address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using bash as your shell,

`if [[ $(curl -s -k http://www.scifi-review.net | grep stettin) ]]; then echo "Subject: Test"| ssmtp myemail@domain.com; fi`

Comment: I figured out the false version `if [[ $(curl -s -k http://www.scifi-review.net | grep xxxxxxxxx) ]]; then echo "there was a match"; else echo "Subject: Test-false"| ssmtp myemail@domain.com; fi`